# State changed but component not re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native, and I use it to build a app now. I found two question today, if anyone can help me understanding these, will be great helpful and appreciate.

In this app, I use `react native` + `Expo` + `redux` + `react-native-elements`( a component lib) +  `react-native-debugger`(debug react-native and redux).

**The First Question(Solved!):**

In my [Auth.js](https://github.com/EzioKissshot/GitBookReader/blob/master/src/Auth.js), I want to render a button, button's string depend on one of state's slice.

```
class Auth extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  // Why this not work???
  // renderBtn(){
  //   btnString = this.props.isLoginPage?"Log In":"Sign Up";
  //   return(
  //     <Button
  //         title={btnString}
  //         big
  //         backgroundColor="#64B5F6"
  //         onPress={this.props.onAuth}
  //       />
  //   )
  // }

  //this works well
  renderBtn(){
    if (this.props.isLoginPage) {
      return(
        <Button
          title="Log In"
          big
          backgroundColor="#64B5F6"
          onPress={this.props.onAuth}
        />
      );
    }

      return(
        <Button
          title="Sign Up"
          big
          backgroundColor="#64B5F6"
          onPress={this.props.onAuth}
        />
      );
  }

...

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
      ...

        {this.renderBtn()}

      ...

      </View>

    )
  }
}
//map isLoginPage from state to props
const mapStateToProps = ({auth}) => {
  const {emailErrorMsg,passwordErrorMsg,email,password,isLoginPage,isLoading} = auth;
  return {emailErrorMsg,passwordErrorMsg,email,password,isLoginPage,isLoading};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{
  onPasswordChanged,
  onEmailChanged,
  onAuth,
  onSwitchAuthType
})(Auth);
```

As above, I want to use `this.props.isLoginPage` to determine show which string. "isLoginPage" is a slice of state which use `react-redux` to map to component's props.

And when I click a button to reverse isLoginPage, and the debugger show that it's changed, but the function `renderBtn()` which I commented is not working, it's just no response, the below `renderBtn()` works well.

The [Button component](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/master/src/buttons/Button.js) is from `react-native-elements`.

I want to know why it happend and if have any documents will be great helpful.

**The Sencond Question:**

In [AuthReducer.js](https://github.com/EzioKissshot/GitBookReader/blob/master/src/reducer/AuthReducer.js) (use by Auth.js above) .I want to reverse isLoginPage

```
import {PASSWORD_CHANGE,EMAIL_CHANGE,SWITCH_AUTH_TYPE,AUTH_START} from '../Type';

const INIT_STATE = {
  isLoginPage:false,

  isLoading:false,
  email:'',
  password:'',
  emailErrorMsg:'',
  passwordErrorMsg:'',
};


export default (state = INIT_STATE, action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case EMAIL_CHANGE:
      return {...state, email:action.payload};
    case PASSWORD_CHANGE:
      return {...state, password:action.payload};

    case SWITCH_AUTH_TYPE:
      //Why this not work???
      //return {...state, isLoginPage:!state.isLoginPage}
      const newIsLogin = !state.isLoginPage;
      return {...state,isLoginPage:newIsLogin};

    case AUTH_START:
      return {...state,isLoading:true};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I commented the not working code (the isLoginPage value is not change, by `react-native-debugger`), the below code is working well.
Seems totally same. I can't understand it, I have any missing with `ES6`?

Comment: `btnString` ? it should `let btnString`

Comment: @JigarShah Oh, I see, what a stupid mistake! Thank you a lot.

Comment: And Question 2 also solved , I don't know what happend , it just disappeared, maybe build tools have some issue?

Comment: probably... but glad to hear

Comment: @JigarShah Can you post a answer so I can accept your answer to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed declaring variable, it should be

```
let btnString = this.props.isLoginPage?"Log In":"Sign Up";
```

With ESLint it should be:

```
let btnString = this.props.isLoginPage ? 'Log In' : 'Sign Up';
```